# How to select lines from a file using Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to check each line in a file for a string and print that line if it has that string.

Example of the array:

```
---
BIP1288I: Message flow 'flow1' on execution group 'EG1' is running.

Additional thread instances: '0'
Deployed: '11/12/13 1:54 AM' in Bar file '/MSD/deploy/ENV/EG1/flow1.bar'
Last edited: '5/24/13 4:38 PM'.
Long description: ''
User-defined property names:
Keywords:

---
BIP1288I: Message flow 'flow2' on execution group 'EG1' is running.

Additional thread instances: '0'
Deployed: '11/12/13 1:54 AM' in Bar file '/MSD/deploy/ENV/EG1/flow2.bar'
Last edited: '5/24/13 4:38 PM'.
Long description: ''
Keywords:

----
BIP1288I: Message flow 'flow3' on execution group 'EG1' is running.

Additional thread instances: '0'
Deployed: '11/12/13 1:54 AM' in Bar file '/MSD/deploy/ENV/EG1/flow3.bar'
Last edited: '5/24/13 4:38 PM'.
Long description: ''
User-defined property names:
  'DBSchema' = 'SIDBT01'
  'LogLevel' = 'ERROR'
Keywords:
```

I am checking each line of this file to check for BIP1288I and flow name 'flow1'. I want my output to contain just this

```
Additional thread instances: '0'
Deployed: '11/12/13 1:54 AM' in Bar file '/MSD/deploy/ENV/EG1/flow1.bar'
Last edited: '5/24/13 4:38 PM'.
```

This is my Perl code

```
foreach $line (@flows) {
  next if /^(\s)*$/;
  if ($line =~ "BIP1288I" && $line =~ "flow1") {
    $msg = "Flow found\n$line\n";
print "$msg";
  }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the array `@flows` contains all the lines of your posted data.

```
use warnings; #always use these modules!
use strict; #always use these modules!

my $flag=0; #a flag to track if we found BIP1288I & flow1 in order to print the lines that follow
for my $line (@flows) {
    if ($flag==1) {
        if ($line=~/^(?:Additional thread|Deployed)/) {
            print $line; #we print the line only if flag is 1 and the line start with the words "Additional thread" or "Deployed" or "Last edited"
        }
        elsif ($line=~/^Last edited/) {
            print $line; #we print the line only if flag is 1 and the line start with the words "Additional thread" or "Deployed" or "Last edited" 
            $flag=0; #we reset the flag
        }
    }
    if ($line=~/BIP1288I: Message flow 'flow1'/) { #this the flow we are interested in
        $flag=1; #set the flag to 1 so we can start printing the lines that will follow
    }
}
```

This will print:

```
Additional thread instances: '0'
Deployed: '11/12/13 1:54 AM' in Bar file '/MSD/deploy/ENV/EG1/flow1.bar'
Last edited: '5/24/13 4:38 PM'.
```

Comment: `strict` and `warnings` are properly called `pragmas`. These are a special kind of module that affect compilation. They are lexically scoped and can be turned off with `no` <pragmaname>.

Comment: I have similar request but now to just get the /MSD/deploy/ENV/EG1/flow.bar. I tried using regex `if (/in Bar file '(.*?)'/){` for the above text but it doesn't give me anything. My output should just be `/MSD/deploy/ENV/EG1/flow1.bar`

Comment: are you sure this doesn't work?: `for (@flows) { print "$1\n" if / in Bar file \'(.*?)\'/ }`

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear to me if you actually need to use `perl`, but this is quite simple with `awk`:

```
awk '/BIP1288I/ && /flow1/ { split($0, a, "\n"); print a[4],a[5],a[6]}' \
    RS=--- OFS=\\n input-file
```

You can use `a2p` to generate the similar script in `perl`.  (`a2p` is the awk to perl translator.  `perl` was largely modelled on `awk`.  Never forget your roots.)  Or:

```
perl -wnE 'BEGIN{ $/="---"; $,="\n"}; 
    @a=split("\n"); say $a[3],$a[4],$a[5] if (m/BIP1288I/ && m/flow1/)' input-file
```

This is not a tight test, since it will act if the strings appear anywhere in the record, but it should be sufficient.  You might need to match `BIP1288I.*flow1` or restrict the match to the first line, depending on your requirements.

Comment: How do your scripts match for both "BIP1288I"  and "flow1" in each record, as the OP specified?

Comment: "Never forget your roots."  You mean like ed->sed->awk->Perl?

Comment: I did not notice the requirement to match "flow1"...will edit.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty unclear to me what you mean, but maybe grep can help you:

```
grep "pattern1" your_file | grep "pattern2"
```

will print lines containing BOTH pattern1 and pattern2

```
egrep "pattern1|pattern2" your_file
```

will print lines containing either pattern.

```
grep -v "pattern" your_file
```

will print lines not matching pattern.

So maybe you can use somethinhg like:

```
egrep "^Additional|flow1|^Last" your_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the following will be helpful:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

local $/ = '---';

while (<>) {
    print "$1$2$3\n"
      if /BIP1288I:.+'flow1'.+\n(Addi[^\n]+\n)(Depl[^\n]+\n)(Last[^\n]+\n)/s;
}
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile [>outFile]`

The last, optional parameter directs output to a file.

Output on your dataset:

```
Additional thread instances: '0'
Deployed: '11/12/13 1:54 AM' in Bar file '/MSD/deploy/ENV/EG1/flow1.bar'
Last edited: '5/24/13 4:38 PM'
```

Assuming that "---" separates records, you can set Perl's record separator (`$/`) to "---" so you file's read in chunks of those records.  Then you can match for "BIP1288I" and flow name "flow1" and capture the other info you want.

Hope this helps!